# javascript: How to get title attribute value from checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, sum

```
 window.onload = function(){
      cds = document.getElementsByName( "cd[]" );
      for( var i = 0; i < cds.length; i++ ){
          cds[i].addEventListener("change", addCDToCart, false );
      }
 } 

 /**
   * this function is called
   * when a CD checkbox is selected
   */
  var addCDToCart = function(){
      //get total cost textbox value
      var txtTotal = $("total");
       // loop through all the checkboxes
       for( var i = 0; i < cds.length; i++ ){
           if( cds[i].checked == true ){
               var nextCD = parseFloat(cds[i].title );
               total = ((total) + (nextCD));
           }
       }
       txtTotal.value = total.toString();
       alert( total.toString() );
  }
```

I used the above code to check for all the checkboxes in an array. I wanted to sum up all the price for all selected checkboxes. The problem is the price is stored in the title attribute and not the value attribute. I tried checking 2 checkboxes with price of 8.20 and 12.70, from the title attribute using the above code and sum them up, but it display something like this:

```
[object HTMLinputElement]8.212.7
```

My assignment says that I am not suppose to modify the HTML code. Below shows a portion of the HTML code:

```
<div class='item'>
        <span class='CDTitle'>Where is the Love</span>
        <span class='CDYear'>2000</span>
        <span class='catDesc'>Rap</span>
        <span class='CDPrice'>12.70</span>
        <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='cd[]' value='974' title='12.70' /></span>
</div>
<div class='item'>
        <span class='CDTitle'>White Ladder</span>
        <span class='CDYear'>2000</span>
        <span class='catDesc'>Rock/Pop</span>
        <span class='CDPrice'>8.20</span>
        <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='cd[]' value='975' title='8.20' /></span>
</div>
```

Any tips for solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using regular javascript *and* jquery?

Comment: @JohnConde I am just using regular javascript only.

Comment: `cds[i].getAttribute('name');`

Comment: You're getting the title correctly by using `.title` on the input.

Comment: I solved a similar problem with node and mongoDB by populating a table from the database. I was able to post all check boxed items and their corresponding rows, where you can get other values. I doubt this is the easiest way to go.

Comment: What are you doing here `$("title")` I'm new to jQuery but that doesn't look like a proper selector

Comment: @PRPGFerret: It's not jQuery. OP stated that in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `title` correctly.

The problem seems to be with the initialization of the `total` variable *(not shown in the question)*, which appears to have a `HTMLInputElement`, which is causing string concatenation of your numeric values.

Perhaps in your actual code you conflated the `total` variable with the `txtTotal`, which holds the `input` element.

Comment: I am quite new with javascript. Can you explain what is $("total")?

Comment: @Boon: The `$` is just a variable. Likely you have a library loaded that has assigned a function to `$`. Some libraries make it a shortcut for `document.getElementById()`. It seems from your use that that's the case, since it seems to return a DOM element.